# Retrieve data from the server without going to a new web page

Tags: html

I use a frame from a HTML page to load some data from the server without having to leave the original web page. I simply reassign the src of the frame and the shown data gets updated.

Now I need to programatically create a div, but the width and height have to be retrieved from the server. May I use a frame to get those values, without leaving the web page, or is there a more simple and efficiente way ?

I would prefer not to use ajax, and keep my code as simple as possible, thanks

Comment: *keep my code as simple as possible* is not a simple task, it is what a programmer works for his whole life, making clean and clever code. Then, you have to learn, and probably learn that Ajax is pretty simple as well.

Comment: any particular reason for not using ajax? this is what ajax is for: updating page content without navigating away...

Comment: The newest standard HTML5 has no frames. If you use jQuery or another library your code will remain simple.

Answer (score 0):

One easiest way is to call page property like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var width = <%=this.Width %>
</script>
```

and declare this property in cs file like this

```
public int Width
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

Is it what you expected? or if you have some calculations after pages loaded, you can simply achieve it by using jquery ajax and one httphanlder.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. It's really simple.

A simple example:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
   $('#result').load('otherfile.php');​
</script>

<div id="result"> </div>
```

Loads otherfile.php inside the div id'ed "result". No page reload.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the jquery example, I may use it in the future. For now I found a very simple and efficient way to solve it using a frame (I know, I know...) that really surprised me for its simplicity:

I create a form (a javascript class that manages several divs), then a little frame inside it, and the frame change the form properties and remove itself.

The key was to access the javascript variable defined in the parent from the child:

```
  echo "<script>";
  echo "parent.window.oDlg.SetSize( ".$row[ "WIDTH" ].", ".$row[ "HEIGHT" ]." );";
  echo "parent.window.oDlg.SetTitle( '".trim( $row[ "TITLE" ] )."' );";
  echo "</script>";
```